# Marketing Cloud - Web recommendations

Tags: marketing-cloud, web, einstein-recommendations

I'm trying to set up the tracking code in an online store, but I'm not sure how I can create the dynamic code for the scripts (for example, find the item ID) without being manually.

Can anyone help me or show an example of a script?

Answer (score 3):

This is out of scope for Marketing Cloud, as this highly depends on the CMS system behind your website. In many cases these variables are available within data layer of already implemented Google Tag Manager. Otherwise you will need to develop an integration using backend code (e.g PHP for Magento) to pass variables from the CMS to the Web & Mobile Collect.
Please align without your e-com team on this.